# UICollectionView Only Allows First Cell to be selected

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm using a UICollectionView to display products from an external API. The products show in the collection view perfectly, but for some reason I cannot select any of the cells. I can select the first cell, but only when I scroll up and then quickly tap the first cell. I'm using the storyboard to create a segue, and in the controller I'm passing data to the next view. The code is below:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: ProductsViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("productViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ProductsViewCell

    let product = tableData[indexPath.row]

    cell.configureWithProduct(product, categoryId: "")

    return cell
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    print("Cell \(indexPath.row) selected")
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if (segue.identifier == "productDetails") {
        let svc = segue.destinationViewController as! ProductViewController;

        let indexPaths : NSArray = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForSelectedItems()!
        let indexPath : NSIndexPath = indexPaths[0] as! NSIndexPath

        let product = tableData[indexPath.row]
        svc.productId = product["merged"][0]["id"].int

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your segue goes from your collectionView cell to your ViewController

Check if prepareForSegue is being called, and your didSelectItemAtIndexPath is also being called when you try to click your cell.

Also check if you have any views on top of your collectionView

Make sure you have those selected.

[View Interaction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHWzS.png)

Comment: The didSelectItemAtIndexPath isn't being called, it shows a print statement, and that statement isn't being shown. I just verified there's no view above the collection view. The collection view scrolls fine, but I cannot select a cell.

Comment: Figured it out. I added a view for a gesture in the code and didn't account for it. Thanks!

Comment: Great that you figured it out